# How to make a P2P streaming using a web browser?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, browser, video

I want to create an application for P2P video transmission. In more details, I need the following:

1. User can switch on a web camera by clicking a button in an application.
2. Application starts to take images from the web camera and sends them to a certain location (given by a port and IP address).
3. Application starts to accept images send by another application and display them (images) in a window.

There is also one more thing. I would prefer to have everything in a browser. I know that everything can be done with Flash Player from Adobe (an example is http://chatroulette.com/).

But I would like to know if the same can be done with JavaScripts.

I am sure it the application can be written in Java. But can I use Java to have everything in a Browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that webcam access is available in any of the browsers natively yet so you might be out of luck for a pure js solution. I think there's meant to be something added to the spec soon though.

If you want to do it with flash (which is really the best way at present) take a look at red5 which you can run on the server to sit between the clients and deal with the video streaming.